# insert into a table using the Select statement and from function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert into a table using the Select statement and get values from function.

```
INSERT INTO  TABLE1 
          ([Col1]
           , [Col2]
           ,[Col3]
           ,[Col4]
           ,[Col5]
           ,[CreationDate]
           ,[CreatedBy]                  
           )  
           VALUES         
 ((Select [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4
  FROM TABLE2)dbo.FUNTION(paramiter) ,SYSDATETIME(), UPPER('USERNAME'))
```

NOTE: im usring SQL SERVER 2008R2. please let me know how to do this?

Thanks guys
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your select statement work first, and then INSERT INTO TABLE1 ([col1], [col2]...) SELECT...

Since your Select statement is broken right now, the insert is also broken.  Fix your select to something like

```
Select [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4],dbo.FUNCTION(parameter), SYSDATETIME(), UPPER('USERNAME')
  FROM TABLE2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this syntax:

`INSERT INTO table(columns) SELECT ...`